# Determine if a string is present in an array starting with another set of strings in another array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm not sure if I explained it well in the title but here is an example:

I have two arrays: I want to take each string in arr2 and look if there is a match in arr1.

```
let arr1 = ["Apple","Ape","Orange","Apricot","Pineapple"]
let arr2 = ["Ap","Or"]
```

I want to get the following array back (in whatever order):

```
["Apple","Ape","Orange","Apricot"]
```

I found .includes() but it does search only for full match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a library, just `filter` the first array by whether `some` of the second array's substrings are contained in the word being iterated over:

```js
let arr1 = ["Apple","Ape","Orange","Apricot","Pineapple"]
let arr2 = ["Ap","Or"]
console.log(
  arr1.filter((word) => arr2.some(substr => word.includes(substr)))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A traditional way is to use two iteration to check it by using `indexOf()`

```js
let arr1 = ["Apple","Ape","Orange","Apricot","Pineapple"]
let arr2 = ["Ap","Or"]

for(var i in arr1){
  for(var j in arr2){
     if(arr1[i].indexOf(arr2[j]) == 0){
       console.log(arr1[i]);
       break;
     }
  }
}
```